# How do I create a new line when using termion in raw mode?

Tags: console, rust, stdout

I am using the [termion crate](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.1/termion/) to capture user input keys with `termion::raw::IntoRawMode` like a event listener. I am unable to print a new line in the console because stdout is in "raw mode" and `\n` is not recognized as a new line. I don't know how to disable raw mode when `draw_user` method is called and then return to raw mode in order to listen to key events again.

The second line starts with white spaces before, but I don't know why:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
extern crate termion;

use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut x: u16 = 1;
    let mut y: u16 = 1;
    // Get the standard input stream.
    let stdin = stdin();
    // Get the standard output stream and go to raw mode.
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    write!(
        stdout,
        "{}{}{}",
        // Clear the screen.
        termion::clear::All,
        // Goto (1,1).
        termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
        // Hide the cursor.
        termion::cursor::Hide
    ).unwrap();
    // Flush stdout (i.e. make the output appear).
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    for c in stdin.keys() {
        // Clear the current line.
        write!(
            stdout,
            "{}{}{}",
            termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
            termion::clear::CurrentLine,
            termion::clear::BeforeCursor
        ).unwrap();

        // Print the key we type...
        match c.unwrap() {
            // Exit.
            Key::Char('q') => break,
            Key::Ctrl('c') => break,
            Key::Left => {
                x -= 1;
                draw_user(&mut x, &mut y);
            }
            Key::Right => {
                x += 1;
                draw_user(&mut x, &mut y);
            }
            Key::Up => {
                y -= 1;
                draw_user(&mut x, &mut y);
            }
            Key::Down => {
                y += 1;
                draw_user(&mut x, &mut y);
            }
            _ => println!(""),
        }
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
    // Show the cursor again before we exit.
    write!(
        stdout,
        "{}{}",
        termion::cursor::Show,
        termion::clear::AfterCursor
    ).unwrap();
    // Flush again.
}

fn draw_user(x: &mut u16, y: &mut u16) {
    let termsize = termion::terminal_size().ok();
    let termwidth = termsize.map(|(w, _)| w - 10).unwrap();
    let termheight = termsize.map(|(_, h)| h).unwrap();
    if *x < 1 {
        *x = 1;
    }
    if *x > termwidth {
        *x = termwidth;
    }
    if *y < 1 {
        *y = 1;
    }
    if *y > termheight {
        *y = termheight;
    }
    //println!("x:{}, y:{}", *x, *y);
    for h in 1..termheight + 1 {
        for w in 1..termwidth + 1 {
            //print!("w:{}",w);
            if h == *y && w == *x {
                print!("☺");
            } else {
                print!("*");
            }
        }
        println!("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The terminal emulator probably is in teletype emulation mode and wants carriage return (`\r`) as well as line feed (`\n`).

Answer (score 26):

Strictly speaking the newline character `\n` means "go to the next line at the same position". In order to start at the beginning of the line you need to add a carriage return `\r`, which means "go to the beginning of the current line". This is why text files in Windows use the `\r\n` combination to mark the end of line. Unix and MacOS have decided that the distinction didn't make sense for computer files and took one extra byte at a time when space was at a premium, so they decided to use a single character in text files. For the same reason computer consoles have two modes, one in which they automatically add a carriage return when they receive a newline (to reduce the amount of data transmitted when the consoles were connected through a serial line) and one in which they apply strictly what they are sent (for fine-grained control). Since you have called `stdout().into_raw_mode()`, you are in the second mode and need to output the carriage return manually.

This behaviour was inherited from the old mechanical typewriters were "newline" was a key that advanced the paper by one line and "carriage return" was a handle that allowed to manually move the carriage back to the start position.

Comment: It's actually `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're right, using `\r` is working :), thank's bro :)