How can I print text without jumping and move the cursor without text moving?
I've been trying to implement a simple terminal text editor using the crossterm crate and I'm able to create the screen and implement the cursor movements for basic h,j,k,l keys and I'm able to print text to the screen. However the issue I'm having is when I read some text files and print them to the terminal the lines are jumping like a stairway and with the cursor movement the text is movement. How can I fix this. What should I do if I want to render the text as it in the file and edit the text with the cursor movement and text insertion.
Here is my code:
use core::panic;
use crossterm::event::{poll, read, Event, KeyCode, KeyModifiers};
use crossterm::terminal::{self, ClearType};
use crossterm::ExecutableCommand;
use crossterm::QueueableCommand;
use crossterm::{cursor, style};
use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

mod filehandle;
mod filepicker;

use filehandle::fileopen;

fn main() {
    let contents = fileopen::openfile();

    let mut stdout = stdout();
    let _ = stdout.execute(terminal::EnterAlternateScreen);
    let _ = terminal::enable_raw_mode();
    let (x, y) = terminal::size().unwrap();
    terminal::SetSize(x, y);
    let wsize = terminal::window_size();
    let _ws = match wsize {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(err) => panic!("Error in getting window size {:?}", err),
    };

    let mut quit = false;
    let mut column: u16 = 0;
    let mut row: u16 = 0;
    let mut esc = false;

    let cur = stdout.execute(cursor::EnableBlinking);
    stdout.queue(terminal::Clear(ClearType::All)).unwrap();

    stdout.execute(cursor::SetCursorStyle::BlinkingBlock);
    while !quit {
        while poll(Duration::ZERO).unwrap() {
            match read().unwrap() {
                Event::Resize(x, y) => {
                    terminal::SetSize(x, y);
                }
                Event::FocusGained => println!("FocusGained"),
                Event::FocusLost => println!("FocusLost"),
                Event::Key(event) => match event.code {
                    KeyCode::Char(x) => {
                        if x == 'c' && event.modifiers.contains(KeyModifiers::CONTROL) {
                            quit = true
                        } else if x == 'j' && esc {
                            row += 1;
                        } else if x == 'k' && esc {
                            if row != 0 {
                                row -= 1;
                            }
                        } else if x == 'l' && esc {
                            column += 1;
                        } else if x == 'h' && esc {
                            if column != 0 {
                                column -= 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    KeyCode::Esc => {
                        if esc {
                            esc = false;
                        } else {
                            esc = true;
                        }
                    }
                    KeyCode::Enter => println!("Enter pressed\r"),
                    _ => todo!(),
                },
                Event::Mouse(MouseEvent) => todo!(),
                Event::Paste(string) => todo!(),
            }
        }

        stdout.execute(style::Print(contents.clone()));
        stdout.execute(cursor::MoveTo(column, row));
        stdout.flush();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(16.66666 as u64));
        stdout.execute(terminal::Clear(ClearType::All));
    }

    terminal::disable_raw_mode();
    stdout.execute(terminal::LeaveAlternateScreen);
}


The "staircasing" means your file has newline without carriage return.  In general in a full-screen text editor, you can't just blast the file out with a single command.  You're going to have to display it line by line, and reset the cursor to column 0 in the next line.  Also, what will you do about lines wider than the screen?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48494508/5397009

thank you i had to print every line with '\r\n" to print correctly. it fixed the issue
